# How to extract data for glVertexPointer() and glColorPointer() from a single array in PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, pointers, opengl, pyopengl

I'm starting to learn PyOpenGL, and I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5BV4a57Tv0) tutorial. At one point the instructor creates a single array from which he extracts the information to construct a triangle: vetices and their color (I added the Numpy line here):

```
#-----------|-Vertices pos--|---Colors----|-----------
vertices = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.0,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

vertices = np.array(vertices, dtype = np.float32)
```

The information of this array is passed to [glVertexPointer() and glColorPointer()](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glColorPointer.html) in the display function:

```
def display():

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)      
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 12, vertices)
    glColorPointer(3, GLFLOAT, 12, vertices + 3)

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
    glutSwapBuffers()
```

My problem is with the last argument of those functions, in the tutorial (since he is using C++), he can write `vertices + 3` in order to tell the program to start reading from the third position of the array, I cannot do this in python.
Can some one guide me on how can I define this pointer? Or how can extract the information from my array.

Note: I'm aware that I can split the information of vertices and colors in differnt arrays, but I want to know if it is possible to do it using one array.

**EDIT** - Adding the complete code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
import numpy as np
import ctypes

#-----------|-Vertices pos--|---Colors----|-----------
vertices = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.0,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
vertices = np.array(vertices, dtype = np.float32)

buffer_offset = ctypes.c_void_p
float_size = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)

#-----------------------------------------------------

def display():

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)      
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 24, buffer_offset(vertices.ctypes.data))
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 24, buffer_offset(vertices.ctypes.data + float_size * 3))

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
    glutSwapBuffers()

def reshape(w,h):
    glViewport(0,0,w,h)

def initOpenGL():
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1)

#-----------------------------------------------------

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH)
glutInitWindowSize(500,500)
glutCreateWindow(b'Test')

glutDisplayFunc(display)
glutIdleFunc(display)
glutReshapeFunc(reshape)

initOpenGL()
glutMainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether you have a vertex buffer bound or not. The last parameter `pointer` in `gl*Pointer()` is either.

- *No Vertex Buffer Bound:* It's the address to the vertices
- *Vertex Buffer Bound:* It's a relative offset in relation to the address of the buffer

You can utilize `ctypes` for this.

```
import ctypes

buffer_offset = ctypes.c_void_p
float_size = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)
```

Assuming you have a vertex buffer bound, then you'd simply do:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 12, buffer_offset(0))
glColorPointer(3, GLFLOAT, 12, buffer_offset(float_size * 3))
```

If you are just using that array and nothing else, then I would assume you could just get the address and equally offset it.

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 12, buffer_offset(vertices.ctypes.data))
glColorPointer(3, GLFLOAT, 12, buffer_offset(vertices.ctypes.data + float_size * 3))
```

*But I have to admit, I've never had the need for this in Python, so I can't confirm it.*

Comment: Thank you very much, that last information you added did the work. I still don't have very clear what is it doing. But I'll find out. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! `vertices.ctypes.data` returns the address of the array. So the first 4 bytes (size of a float) at the address, will be the first element in `vertices` and so on (every 4 bytes). Thus if we take the `address + 4 * 3`, then that will be the address of the first color element. You already tell the stride (24 bytes), that's why it only needs to know the starting address. The stride is 24 bytes because you have 6 floats (X, Y, Z, R, G, B). `6 floats * 4 float_size = 24 bytes`.